# How to call a method on assert

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to capture as much information when an assert happens and before any clean-up code is called.
Below is a simplified code of what most of our existing tests look like:

In my conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    print('%s: pytest_runtest_makereport(%s)' % (datetime.now(), call))

def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    print('\n%s: pytest_exception_interact' % datetime.now())
```

In my test file:

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def marshall_me():
    print('\n%s: starting test' % datetime.now())
    yield marshall_me
    print('\n%s: ending test' % datetime.now())

class Device(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('\n%s: create object' % datetime.now())
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print('\n%s: clean-up object' % datetime.now())

def test_fails(marshall_me):
    with Device():
        assert False
```

When I run this I get:

```
test_fails.py::test_fails  2017-04-26 17:07:37.447359: starting test
2017-04-26 17:07:37.447453: pytest_runtest_makereport(<CallInfowhen='setup' result: []>) 
2017-04-26 17:07:37.447583: create object
2017-04-26 17:07:37.448397: clean-up object 
2017-04-26 17:07:37.448614: pytest_runtest_makereport(<CallInfowhen='call' exception: assert False>) 
FAILED 
2017-04-26 17:07:37.462267: pytest_exception_interact 
2017-04-26 17:07:37.462353: ending test
2017-04-26 17:07:37.462428: pytest_runtest_makereport(<CallInfo when='teardown' result: []>)
```

I cannot use pytest_runtest_makereport and pytest_exception_interact because they get called after the clean-up function and that would then be too late for me to collect important information. Are there other similar functions that get called at the time that the assert is actually generated?

Answer (score 4):

You have the alternate form of the assert statement:

```
assert <cond>, <expr>
```

which means that the interpreter is first to evaluate the condition and if that's false it will evaluate the expression to be used as argument to `AssertionError`. So to call a function on assertion failure you'd use this:

```
assert condition_to_be_true(), function_to_call_if_not_true()
```

Note that the return value of `function_to_call_if_not_true()` will be used as argument to `AssertionError`. If that's not what you want you will need to do some tricks to change the result of the expression - you can use the boolean operators to do that. No matter what `x` is the expression `(x and False) or y` will evaluate to `y` (by the short circuit rules of python).

To wrap it up you would do:

```
assert condition_to_be_true(), (function_to_call_if_not_true() 
                  and False) or ARGUMENT_TO_AssertionError
```

Another way to do it is to misuse the language if you must (this ought to be considered evil). Since an assert statement is equivalent to after confirming that the condition is false is to raise `AssertionError` you could simply redefine it:

```
class AssertionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        Exception(self, *args, **kwds)
        print("Assertion")

assert condition_to_check()
```

note here that it's the value of `AssertionError` at the current scope of the `assert` statement that you need to redefine.

Comment: Your second alternative works for me as a wholesale solution to our already existing tests.  I understand that this is not how things should have been done and if I had started from scratch, there certainly would be more elegant solutions to use. Thank you.